# PostMessage() succeeds but my message processing code never receives the message

Tags: c++, winapi, user-interface, postmessage

In my C++ application's GUI object I have the following in the main window procedure:

```
case WM_SIZE:
    {
        OutputDebugString(L"WM_SIZE received.\n");
        RECT rect = {0};
        GetWindowRect(hwnd, &rect);
        if (!PostMessage(0, GUI_MSG_SIZECHANGED, w, MAKELONG(rect.bottom - rect.top, rect.right - rect.left))) {
            OutputDebugString(L"PostMessage failed.\n"); // <--- never called
        }
    }

    return 0; // break;
```

The GUI object also has the following getMessage() method:

```
int GUI::getMessage(MSG & msg) {
    BOOL result = 0;

    while ((result = GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0)) > 0) {
        if (msg.message > (GUI_MSG_BASE-1) && msg.message < (GUI_MSG_LAST+1)) {
            OutputDebugString(L"GUI message received.\n");
            break;
        }
        else {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

The application object calls this method in the following way:

```
while ((result = _gui.getMessage(msg)) > 0) {
    switch (msg.message) {
        // TODO: Add gui message handlers
        case GUI_MSG_SIZECHANGED:
            OutputDebugString(L"GUI_MSG_SIZECHANGED received.\n");
            _cfg.setWndWidth(HIWORD(msg.lParam));
            _cfg.setWndHeight(LOWORD(msg.lParam));
            if (msg.wParam == SIZE_MAXIMIZED)
                _cfg.setWndShow(SW_MAXIMIZE);
            else if (msg.wParam == SIZE_MINIMIZED)
                _cfg.setWndShow(SW_MINIMIZE);
            else if (msg.wParam == SIZE_RESTORED)
                _cfg.setWndShow(SW_SHOWNORMAL);
            break;
    }
}
```

The application object is interested in the window size because it stores this information in a configuration file.

When I run this in Visual Studio's debugger, the output window looks like this after resizing the window:

```
WM_SIZE received.
GUI message received.
GUI_MSG_SIZECHANGED received.
WM_SIZE received.
WM_SIZE received.
WM_SIZE received.
WM_SIZE received.
...etc...
```

The PostMessage() function never fails, but seems to only send GUI_MSG_SIZECHANGED (#defined as WM_APP + 0x000d) the first time WM_SIZE is handled, which is right after handling WM_CREATE.

I have no idea what could be causing this. I tried using SendMessage and PostThreadMessage but the result is the same. Also read through MSDN's message handling documentation but couldn't find what's wrong with my code.

Could anyone help?

Comment: Why don't you run a normal message loop. What on earth is the point of the  `while` loop in `GUI::getMessage`? You appear to have two nested message pumps!! I can't get my head round this at all. If you ran a normal message pump it would be easier to be motivated to try to answer the question. As it stands one can only guess at what other weirdness is going on.

Comment: And `(msg.message > (GUI_MSG_BASE-1) && msg.message < (GUI_MSG_LAST+1))` rather than using `>=` and `<=`? Why?

Comment: Try to add some debug output when you enter and leave the `GUI::getMessage` function and after the loop around `_gui.GetMessage`. I think it's something in your programs flow of control that is the problem, but I can't spot exactly where.

Comment: @David The nested message pumps are the result of me trying to keep GUI code and application logic separate. The application object really doesn't care about WM_PAINT for example, so that's handled by the inner pump in the GUI object. However, since the GUI is also an input mechanism, the app object needs to be notified of certain things, like when the user selects a file to open, or, in this case, when the window is resized... I guess my underlying problem is OO design... If object B is a member of object A, how can B notify A of certain events?

Comment: nested message pump cannot be right solution

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hacking a custom message loop is something you'll live to regret some day.  You hit it early.

Don't post messages with a NULL window handle, they can only work if you can guarantee that your program only ever pumps your custom message loop.  You cannot make such a guarantee.  These messages fall into the bit bucket as soon as you start a dialog or Windows decides to pump a message loop itself.  Which is the case when the user resizes a window, the resize logic is modal.  Windows pumps its own message loop, WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE announces it.  This is also the reason that PostThreadMessage is *evil* if the thread is capable of displaying any window.  Even a MessageBox is fatal.  DispatchMessage cannot deliver the message.

Create a hidden window that acts as the controller.  Now you can detect GUI_MSG_SIZECHANGED in its window procedure and no hacks to the message loop are necessary.  That controller is not infrequently the main window of your app btw.

Comment: Although I don't really like the idea of a hidden window inside my app object (as I'm trying to keep GUI code in my GUI object), this is probably what I will end up doing if I can't figure out a more elegant solution. Please read my reply to David, perhaps you have some nice input to my OO design question.

Comment: I'm okay with thread messages being dropped on the floor during modal sizing loops, but then *how does the first one get through*? :)

Comment: @Frédéric - the first one is probably a WM_SIZE from the initial window creation.  Something like that.